# Dynamically regenerate model when DB changes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to have entity framework dynamically add/remove tables/columns in its `DbContext` without recompiling the project ? The use case is EF inside a GUI app and the DB schema may be changed behind the scenes over the lifetime - we don't want the GUI app to be recompiled on every DB change - it should just visually show the new table classes (i.e. Schema) as well as a few controls like type, property name etc.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework does not do that. It would be custom solution, pretty expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically not possible if your GUI app works with your database without some detached "api" - real web api, wcf service, etc. Even if you disable automatic migration for project and will manage to make your application think, that database is up-to-date (which can probably happen with some magic, dynamic DLL compilation, etc.), you have a big possibility of getting something funky - changed FK, PK, restrictions, constraints, data types, etc.. This will cause unexpected behavior for Entity Framework, and bring only grief.

Only in this case you can do it without affecting real GUI app - you just re-roll external project and voila - it works, if you properly set up your DTOs and methods. Otherwise, if your API changes uncontrollably, you will get DTO mismatch problems, which you will have to handle with versioning, etc, etc.

It's overall a bad idea to change model backing your application in any casewithout recompilation, since C# is not a dynamic language.